# vim is messed up in iterm

Tags: macvim, iterm2

I installed both mvim(macvim) and vim through brew. vim was installed using "brew install vim " (with python3, doesn't matter ). The OS is High Sierra.

While mvim is completely fine, vim is completely messed up. For example, when I type gg, it goes to the top of the page instead of to the start. And I can't progress upwards. It sometimes overrides things like --insert--.

I disabled powerline and many other features. It still happens. 
It works fine in terminal (as far as I could judge). It just doesn't work in iterm (also after changing the fonts back to default).

Thanks.

Comment: `It works fine in terminal [...] It just doesn't work in iterm` so you mean that it works in another terminal emulator than iterm? That would mean that the problem comes from iterm not vim. Also have to tried starting vim without any config just to be sure that the problem doesn't come from your vimrc? You could also have a look at the output of `:scriptname` to see if something messes up your config.

Comment: please try first without any plugins. See also the [faq](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-2.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FAQ was really helpful at troubleshooting. I had these lines in .vimrc, so I added the if.

```
if has('gui_running')
   set lines=75
   set scrolloff=3
endif
```